# How can I fetch a NULL boolean from Postgres in Go?

Tags: postgresql, go, boolean

Go's zero value for a bool type is `false`. Postgres supports an undefined BOOL type, represented as NULL.  This leads to problems when trying to fetch a BOOL value from Postgres in Go:

```
rows,err := db.Query("SELECT UNNEST('{TRUE,FALSE,NULL}'::BOOL[])");
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
for rows.Next() {
    var value bool
    if err := rows.Scan(&value); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Value: %t\n",value);
}
```

Output:

```
Value: true  
Value: false  
2014/11/17 09:34:26 sql: Scan error on column index 0: sql/driver: couldn't convert <nil> (<nil>) into type bool
```

What's the most idiomatic way around this problem? The two solutions I have imagined are neither very attractive:

1. Don't use Go's `bool` type. Instead I would probably use a string, and do my own conversion which accounts for `nil`
2. Always make sure BOOLs are either TRUE or FALSE in Postgres by using `COALESCE()` or some other means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My preference is using a pointer:

```
for rows.Next() {
    var value *bool

    if err := rows.Scan(&value); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if value == nil {
        // Handle nil
    }

    fmt.Printf("Value: %t\n", *value);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

See http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullBool in the standard library.

> NullBool represents a bool that may be null. NullBool implements the
>   Scanner interface so it can be used as a scan destination, similar to
>   NullString.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using SQL + graphQL (gqlgen) my preference is using pointers as well.

Why?

Because when I generate a schema it will have pointers on the output and this is much easy to connect with  a relevant struct which contains pointers (which handle DB operations).