# How to scan a boolean, which may be NULL?

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx

I try to scan a boolean result into a boolean pointer:

```golang
var expired bool
db.QueryRow(context.Background(), sql, id, n).Scan(&expired)
```

The code fails with the following error:

> can't scan into dest[0]: cannot scan NULL into *bool

Which Go type do I have to use to scan a SQL boolean, which can be true, false and NULL?

Comment: Use a pointer (e.g. `var expired *bool`) or a custom type ([pgx](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v5@v5.4.0/pgtype#hdr-Null_Values), [stdlib](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#NullBool)). The [pgx docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx#hdr-Null_Mapping) have more info (or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26976251/11810946) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28642838/11810946)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preference is using a pointer for `bool`

```golang
var expired *bool
db.QueryRow(context.Background(), sql, id, n).Scan(&expired)
```

As `bool` only have `false` and `true` values, it does not provide a way to represent `NULL`.

[sql.NullBool](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#NullBool) is alse a good choice.